# Insert a custom Filter in the Spring Security Filter Chain in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-filter

I am working on spring cloud gateway which authenticates with OAuth2 with the help of spring security filter chain. Currently I am having an error at the login page of the OAuth2 because of some unknows authorization request not found error which I need to solve. I have figured a way out by adding a custom location header and route the user to that location when the exception occurs. Currently I am facing challenges while having the control before the spring security filter chain. Below is the code block which I have used:

```
 @Bean
 @Order(1)
 SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity)
  throws Exception {
        ServerRequestCache requestCache = NoOpServerRequestCache.getInstance();
        WebFilter webFilter = new CustomWebFilter();
        serverHttpSecurity
          //.addFilterAt(webFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.FIRST)
          .cors().and().headers()
          .frameOptions().disable()
          .and().requestCache().requestCache(requestCache)
          .and().csrf().disable()
          .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/**").authenticated()
          .and().oauth2Login()
          .and().oauth2Client()
          .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
     return serverHttpSecurity.build();
   }
```

Here I have tried adding the filter before the authentication, but it blocks the request and I get a null response and it doesn't route me to the login page.

```
.addFilterAt(webFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.FIRST)
```

Below is my customWebFilter where I have added code to add the location heade.

```
public class CustomWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Autowired
    URIconfig uRIconfig;
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomWebFilter.class);

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
      URI location = exchange.getRequest().getURI();
      uRIconfig.setLocation(location);
      logger.info("Custom Pre Filter executed");
       return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
 }
```

Can somebody help me add the header or a cookie whichever possible before the request redirects to the OAuth2 login page? Or how can I user the filter?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the order of spring security filter chain to 5 and added an @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) to my custom filter. Now my filter invokes before my keycloak login page and I could add my custom implementation. Below is the changes I have made:

Application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    filter:
      order: 5
```

CustomWebFilter.java

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Slf4j
public class CustomWebFilter implements WebFilter {

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    log.info("My Custom Web Filter.");
    return chain.filter(exchange);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP's answer is correct it works. However, I did not like changing the spring defaults ( as far as I understand spring ).

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    filter:
      order: 5
```

So I took an alternate route and this would also work. Again credit to OP to showing a path on how to do it.

```java
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Slf4j
public class CustomWebFilter implements WebFilter {
    
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    log.info("My Custom Web Filter.");
    return chain.filter(exchange);
  }
}
```

and in your SecurityConfig class you can just do this.

```java
@Bean
@Order(0)
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
   // your config
}
```